# Why can't I progress to the next hotel in Story Mode?

Tags: pokemon-duel

Is the complete story mode for Pokémon Duel not available for the English version? After I completed the Elysium Hotel the next hotel was still locked.

Answer (score 3):

I'm having the same issue. I think I need more stars but that's just a guess. It doesn't give any hints and you can even see the hotels name

---

I just read that elysium hotel is the last hotel at this point in time. Apparently the rest will be released at a later date

Comment: The current update (3.0.2) includes a locked banner that appears over the later hotels when you start Quests mode, and the banner re-appears if you try to touch on any of those later hotels.